# How to add code into the file using terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, nano

```
    sudo touch /etc/test/sc.json
echo Your password:
read pass
echo Your number:
read number

cd /etc/test/
cat <<EOT>> sc.json
{
    "server":"0.0.0.0",
    "password":"$pass",
    "number":"$number"
}
EOT
touch /etc/systemd/system/test.service
cd /etc/systemd/system
cat <<EOT>> test.service
[Unit]
1
 
[Service]
Type=simple
User=nobody
Group=nogroup



EOT
```

Can i use nano to fill the files? Cat doesn't work. I need a script which will create these configuration files on the fresh machine. Prefer not to  install additional software.

Comment: What problems are you having with `cat`?  Are you getting permission errors writing to sc.json?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo touch /etc/test/sc.json
echo Your password:
read pass
echo Your number:
read number

read -r -d '' data << EOF
{
    "server":"0.0.0.0",
    "password":"$pass",
    "number":"$number"
}
EOF
sudo echo $data > /etc/test/sc.json

sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/test.service
read -r -d '' data << EOF
[Unit]
1
 
[Service]
Type=simple
User=nobody
Group=nogroup
EOF
sudo echo $data > /etc/systemd/system/test.service
```

This code will write your data into the files!

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-26-0-178:~$ sudo bash -c "$(wget -qO- https://wpnew.ru/tst)"
touch: cannot touch '/etc/tst/sc.json': No such file or directory
Password:
122
number:
222
bash: line 14: /etc/tst/sc.json: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch '/etc/tst/tst.service': No such file or directory
bash: line 36: /etc/tst/tst.service: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Since you created sc.json as root, you'll need root permissions to write to it.  Thus, bash will fail here:

```
cat <<EOT>> sc.json
```

Rather, you can write to a file owned by root if use `sudo` and `tee` as follows.
Consider this modification:

```
cat <<EOT  | sudo tee /etc/test/sc.json
{
    "server":"0.0.0.0",
    "password":"$pass",
    "number":"$number"
}
EOT
```